# Reference formatting without impacting its discoverability by services like Google Scholar

Tags: citations, google-scholar, bibliometrics

When citing some paper in a manuscript what fields of the BIBTEX we can change/remove without impacting the citation count done by services like Google Scholar?

In other words what are the fields in citations which Google Scholar like services count?

Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Don't expect too much of an answer. Google Scholar is notoriously intransparent, so its inner workings remain a complete mistery.

Answer (score 1):

The doi number seems to help. So does putting a version on Researchgate or Academia. But nobody really knows.

Answer (score 0):

I know a few papers that cited my work but was not discovered by google scholar and not credited in my google scholar profile. Often adding DOI helps.